# API and subscription sharing within a team in Azure API Manager?

Tags: azure-api-management

I have 2 questions.

1. Can I configure an API to be seen and modified only by a selected (by the original owner) set of API developers but not everyone?
2. In the developer portal, can I configure applications/subscription to be seen and modified only by a selected (by the original owner) set of API developers but not everyone?

Thanks.

Comment: 01. You mean only certain APIs or all APIs listed on APIM ? 02. developer portal you can't modified anything, but yes you can set access to only certain developers

Answer (score 1):

1. From management side look into ARM RBAC, it's not an APIM specific feature, but Azure in general. It should allow you to setup RBAC rules to control management access to APIs.
2. From developer portal API visibility is controlled via product visibility, product visibility via developer groups. See Access control settings on a product. Subscriptions are always visible on dev portal only to a user who owns them.

Comment: Thank you. I have a follow up question on the 2nd on. Let's say we have configured keys generated by the Person A to a company App. Now the person A is resigning and his account needs to be deactivated. How can we move the subscription to another account? Thanks.

Comment: Technically you can't. But you can create another subscription for a different account and set it's keys to match old ones. That is after removing the old subscription. Alternatively you could create a subscription not tied to a user at all (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/subscription/createorupdate ownerId is not required), this is a part of our preview API at the moment, but will be exposed in UI soon.